# Cropping picture at center freezes camera android

Tags: android, android-camera

I have taken a picture from camera from front view. Now I want to crop the center of the image, but when I put the code xwidth > xheight inside my `PictureCallback` function, the camera freeze. I am  taking four pictures from the camera like in a burst mode. My objective is to crop each image from center like this:

[image]

without freezing the camera.

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length,options);

            int xxWidth = bitmapPicture.getWidth();
            int xHeight =   bitmapPicture.getHeight();

            if (xxWidth >=xHeight){

                bitmapPicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bitmapPicture, 
                        xxWidth/2 - xHeight/2,
                     0,
                     bitmapPicture.getHeight(), 
                     bitmapPicture.getHeight()
                     );

                }
```

Comment: dont crop in onPictureTaken method.. do in asynctask class.

Comment: picturetaken are in surfaceview and i am taking more than one picture how can i put an asynctask

Comment: then use separate class with activity..

Comment: can you help me in chat discussion please ?

Comment: thanks segi it worked without an async task :)